# How to do type cast for Date and Timestamp fields after schema definition in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, casting, timestamp

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField('bch_date', DateType(), True),
    StructField('model_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('cusip', StringType(), True),
    StructField('hold_cusip', StringType(), True),
    StructField('secr_attoc_stt_ts', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('symbol', StringType(), True),
    StructField('hold_symbol', StringType(), True),
    StructField('secr_alloc_end_ts', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('secr_alloc_pct', DecimalType(), True),
    StructField('updt_reas_cd', StringType(), True),
    StructField('crte_tstp', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('crte_pgm', StringType(), True),
    StructField('crte_usrid', StringType(), True),
    StructField('last_updt_tstp', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('last_updt_pgm', StringType(), True),
    StructField('last_updt_usrid', StringType(), True)
])
```

```py
df_dataframe = (
    spark.read
    .option('header', True)
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .schema(schema)
    .csv('test.csv')
)
```

I am getting null values when I am reading my PySpark dataframe. I want to know, after defining the schema, how to do typecasting for `DateType()` and `TimestampType()`.

Comment: see [`cast`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.cast.html#pyspark-sql-column-cast) method -- also, you might be getting nulls because the date and ts formats are not in default style (`yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` are defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `"dateFormat"` and `"dateFormat"` when reading the file.

Input file:

```py
s = """col_date,col_timestamp
31-12-2022,25-05-2021 11:30:00"""
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Script:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField('col_date', DateType(), True),
    StructField('col_timestamp', TimestampType(), True)
])
df = (
    spark.read
    .option('header', 'true')
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("dateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy")
    .option("timestampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .schema(schema)
    .csv('test.csv')
)

df.show()
# +----------+-------------------+
# |  col_date|      col_timestamp|
# +----------+-------------------+
# |2022-12-31|2021-05-25 11:30:00|
# +----------+-------------------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- col_date: date (nullable = true)
#  |-- col_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```